# FFMPEG - changing pixel format from 24-bit RGB to 8-bit Grayscale only changes color, but not file size

Tags: ffmpeg, grayscale

I am using the avlib* libraries and currently using the sws_getContext function to change pixel format from RGB (AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24) to grayscale (AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8). The expected behavior should have been that the output file size should have decreased by 3 times as we are going from 24 bit rgb to 8 bit grayscale, but it stayed the same. Furthermore, when I checked on Media-Coder to see the format, the video format was still RGB. Any ideas on why the file size didn't change and why the file format is still RGB?

Note: the video DID change to black and white as expected.

Comment: Need details - output codec and relevant snippets of the code

Comment: It's possible it's being "video encoded" back into YUV after being converted to gray...before it hits the output file...

Comment: @rogerdpack  how come the colors are still "greyscale" even if the video is changed back to YUV?

Comment: @Gyan currently no codecs are being used. Can we change the file size with sws_getContext or sws_scale?

Comment: it's hard to tell in this instance.  If you re-encode to h264 at output time then it converts the whole things back to YUV possibly...that's using ffmpeg command line dunno in your case, GL!